# Load resource file based on culture and session state value

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a requirement to change the content of a .Net core mvc web app based on culture[Lauguage] and a particular session value which will be set based on a dropdown selection.

I have a dropdown of States [PA, VA, .. etc], so created resource files viewname.PA.en.resx, viewname.VA.en.resx.

Need to load the appropriate resource file based on my dropdown selection and language culture.

currently it's loading based language culture only.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-5.0#set-the-culture-programmatically-2) and [sample](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/fundamentals/localization/sample/3.x/Localization).

You could create a _SelectLanguagePartial.cshtml partial view with the following code:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Options

@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer
@inject IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions> LocOptions

@{
    var requestCulture = Context.Features.Get<IRequestCultureFeature>();
    var cultureItems = LocOptions.Value.SupportedUICultures
        .Select(c => new SelectListItem { Value = c.Name, Text = c.DisplayName })
        .ToList();
    var returnUrl = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Context.Request.Path) ? "~/" : $"~{Context.Request.Path.Value}";
}

<div title="@Localizer["Request culture provider:"] @requestCulture?.Provider?.GetType().Name">
    <form id="selectLanguage" asp-controller="Home" 
          asp-action="SetLanguage" asp-route-returnUrl="@returnUrl" 
          method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <label asp-for="@requestCulture.RequestCulture.UICulture.Name">@Localizer["Language:"]</label> <select name="culture"
          onchange="this.form.submit();"
          asp-for="@requestCulture.RequestCulture.UICulture.Name" asp-items="cultureItems">
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
```

Then, add the `Views/Shared/_SelectLanguagePartial.cshtml` file is added to the footer section of the layout file so it will be available to all views:

```
<div class="container body-content" style="margin-top:60px">
    @RenderBody()
    <hr>
    <footer>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <p>&copy; @System.DateTime.Now.Year - Localization</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
                @await Html.PartialAsync("_SelectLanguagePartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</div>
```

Then, in Home Controller SetLanguage method, set the culture cookie.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SetLanguage(string culture, string returnUrl)
{
    Response.Cookies.Append(
        CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
        CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(culture)),
        new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(1) }
    );

    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
}
```

[Note] You can't plug in the _SelectLanguagePartial.cshtml to sample code for this project. The Localization.StarterWeb project on GitHub has code to flow the RequestLocalizationOptions to a Razor partial through the Dependency Injection container. Check [the Startup.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y49yC.png).